# MissingManifestResourceException

Tags: compact-framework

I am trying to connect to mysql database from a .NET compact framework using C#. Each time I run the program, I get a missingmanifestresourceexception just at the point of opening the connection.
Can any one please tell me how to go about this, I've lost four days already.

P.S: I already added the reference Mysql.Data.CF.

my code is as below

```
        string MyConString ="SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=kunle;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=olakay;"+ "pooling=false;";


        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        MySqlDataReader Reader;
        command.CommandText = "select * from mycustomers";
        try
        {



            connection.Open(); //***this is the point where I get the error***


            MessageBox.Show("Connected successfully");

        }
        catch (MySqlException asd)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + asd.Message);
        }
        catch (MissingManifestResourceException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex.Message);
        }
        Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            //statement goes here;
        }
        connection.Close();
```

will be looking forward to an answer from anyone.

Olakay.

Comment: So, you have your name as password in the DB? ;o)

Comment: I also got this error. But No Solutions?.

Answer (score 0):

Put "pooling=false" in the connection string. It resolved my problem.

Which version of connector are you using. I have succeeded with 5.2.7

I have posted resolution for this on MySql forum
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,228101,276266#msg-276266

Comment: no it is not, by default (if pooling=false is missing) connectors assumes that pooling=true

Comment: I already addedpooling false.
Yet it does not solve the problem
 Olakay

Comment: huh ... give me your mail to send you the library I am using with the appropriate connection string.

On my device with WindowsCE 5.0 works fine.

Comment: Also ... I hope that you have enabled Wi-Fi and have a valid connection to your network.

Comment: np, I am sending you them now

Comment: want to quickly ask u this. did you connect directly from visual studio or did you deploy it first on your device. And did you have virtual PC installed on your system. Do you think it would help the connection?

Comment: Just used what you sent to me. It's still giving the MissingManifestResourceException.
Any more clue?

Comment: Huh, what version of CF are you using? Which version of MySql you're trying to connect?